# EventListeners for log\history. Doctrine2, Symfony

Tags: symfony, logging, doctrine-orm, history, event-listener

I want to make custom log \ history in order to track what happened. I have such Entities:

> -Category
>
> -Item
>
> -AttrValue
>
> -Attributes

All of them are related to each other like this:
[image]
I read it and decided to use EventListeners and write events to the table using doctrine. You do not need to offer to use bands for logging / auditing, the essence is what you need to do without them. Therefore, I determined such steps to realize this:

1. Create a new Entity with the following fields:

> -Time (When);
>
> -What (the action that occurred, for example, creating, updating, viewing or deleting records);
>
> -OldValue (if it exists);
>
> -NewValue (if it exists);

2. Create a new EventListener with prePersist, preUpdate and preRemove.
3. Create a method that will work with Doctrine and write values ​​from item 1 (something like `buildLog (LifecycleEventArgs $args, $type)`, where `$type` is an action (create, update, or delete).

Therefore, I have such questions:
1. Can I use EventListeners for what I want to do?
2. If so, did I correctly describe the sequence of actions? (to define EventListeners in `services.yml` I do not consider)
3. How to determine what action has occurred? (I will attach my routing file below)
4. How to use this all for several Entities? Something like this will suit?

```
$ entity = $ args-> getEntity ();
```

5. Can there be somewhere a similar implementation, so that you can read?
   My Routing:

   getAllCategory:
       path:      /category
       methods: [GET]
       defaults:  { _controller: AppBundle:Catalog:getAllCategory}

   getCategory:
       path:      /category/{id}
       methods: [GET]
       defaults:  { _controller: AppBundle:Catalog:getCategory}

   postCategory:
       path:      /category
       methods: [POST]
       defaults:  { _controller: AppBundle:Catalog:postCategory}

   updateCategory:
       path: /category
       methods: [PATCH]
       defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Catalog:updateCategory}

   deleteCategory:
       path: /category/{id}
       methods: [DELETE]
       defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Catalog:deleteCategory}

   getAllItem:
       path: /items
       methods: [GET]
       defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Item:getAllItems}

   getItem:
       path: /item/{id}
       methods: [GET]
       defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Item:getItem}
   postItem:
       path: /item
       methods: [POST]
       defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Item:postItem}

   updateItem:
       path: /item
       methods: [PATCH]
       defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Item:updateItem}

   deleteItem:
           path: /item/{id}
           methods: [DELETE]
           defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Item:deleteItem}